# Initialize all variables, always

Tags: c, coding-style

I am reading [the FreeBSD coding style](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~eno/coding/CCodingStandard.html) and am quite liking it (as I like vertically compact code). There is however this:

> Initialize all Variables
>   You shall always initialize variables. Always. Every time. gcc with the flag -W may catch operations on uninitialized variables, but
>   it may also not.
>
> Justification
>   More problems than you can believe are eventually traced back to a pointer or variable left uninitialized.

When there is no appropriate initial value for a variable, isn't it much better to leave it without a value. That way the compiler will probably catch reading it uninitialized. i am not talking about `T *p = NULL`, which is a trap representation and might (or may not) be quite useful, but rather `int personal_number = 0 /* but 0 is a valid personal number!!*/`

---

To clarify, in response to **abasu**'s comment, **my example is trying to illustrate cases when there are no available invalid values**. I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023190/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-reserved-variable-values-for-special-cases) and was answered that using impossible values to mark errors or other conditions is awesome. But it is not always the case. Examples are plentiful: 8bit pixel value, velocity vector, etc.

---

One valid alternative to "Always initialize variables", that I can see is:

```
//logical place for declarations
T a;

/*code, for example to set up the environment for evaluating a*/

a = fooForA();

/*more code*/

fooThatUsesA(a);
```

This way if initialization is forgotten, there will be warning and the bug will be fixed, removing the warning.

Comment: Depends on what makes sense... How about `-1` as an invalid `personal_number`?

Comment: if it is uninitialized also, that does not mean there won't be a value. And that value can be a valid number also (by chance, unexpectedly). So what will be your choice? leaving it to luck and potentially facing a disaster when an uninitialized variable with some valid value creating some unwanted side effect? or spend some 10 secs and figure out an invalid value and make sure your variable is initialized with that (and your program is checking for that of course)

Comment: @abasu, my point is that the compiler or a static analyzer will easily detect the uninitialized value. On the other hand, setting a variable to a _wrong_ _valid_ value can be confusing for both the programmer and the machine.

Comment: @Vorac Ok. The compiler catches it uninitialized and gives you a warning. This is great. What do you do _then_? The "Always initialize variables" is not contrary to taking advantage of that compiler warning. Actually, the warning exists because you are violating the rule in the first place. The question is how you will fix that violation. Or do you seeing warnings in your code that you have uninitialized variables just for the sake of seeing the warning? It doesn't make sense if you don't actually _do_ something about it.

Comment: @Vorac yes, your point is valid. (although i'm not sure, compiler and static analyzer can catch 100% cases, for such, there are run time tools) But the second line, `setting a variable to a wrong valid value` is not this a mistake (i.e. coding error??). if yes, then the confusion is expected. What is expected is not a problem, problem is what is unexpected. :) :) (personal experience)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are *all* integers valid personal numbers?

If not, then use an invalid value to initialize `personal_number`.

If they are, then even when you have not initialized `personal_number` yourself *it still holds a value that is a valid personal number* -- but that value is unknown. So initialize it to `0` anyway -- you have not introduced a problem (valid number before, valid number after), the only difference is that the number is now known to you.

Of course in both cases it would be better to not use an integer literal for initialization, but rather do something like this:

```
enum { INVALID_PERSONAL_NUMBER = -1 }

int personal_number = INVALID_PERSONAL_NUMBER;
```

Comment: You assume there exist invalid value for the variable (because of my bad example). there are cases, where this is not true. They are of interest to me.

Comment: @Vorac he is not assuming anything. He is giving you what I think is the best answer in both cases: If not (...), If they are (...).

Comment: @Vorac: I am indeed not assuming. You commented "setting to a wrong valid value" above -- you have to realize that as it stands, it is *already* set to a wrong valid value (by the compiler).

Comment: Yea, I also like this answer the most. However, while your point is perfectly valid, we **still** loose the ability to use static analysis to catch a bug at compile time, rather than at run-time. I think the truth is somewhere in between your answer and **JeremyP**'s. Let the question remain open for now.

Comment: @Vorac You _already_ caught the bug. You found a variable which is not initialized. What else do you want?

Comment: @Daniel Daranas, uninitialized variable is not a bug. *Reading* such one is. And I still feel that making a habit of using this idiom for declarations is, let's say not the best practice: `T a = 0;`.

Comment: @Vorac Then we disagree. I've found "Always initialize variables" very useful in all the projects I've been in. With my technique, reading an unititalized variable becomes _impossible_ in the first place. Design by Contract, in turn, helps prevent logical errors such as not actually giving a variable a meaningful value. Combined with "Limit variable scope to its minimum possible one." But this is just my experience.

Comment: @Vorac: I see your point, but IMHO Daniel's comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478932/initialize-all-variables-always/16479017#comment23648180_16478932) is right on the money.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers often don't catch reading variables uninitialized.  Instead, they're likely to use that information to make assumptions about the rest of the code to perform optimization, possibly introducing new and worse bugs:

```
int get_personal_number(const char *name)
{
    int personal_number;
    if (name != NULL) {
        /* look up name in some array */
        personal_number = ...
    }
    return personal_number;
}
```

An optimising compiler will *infer* that `name` cannot be `NULL` and eliminate the check.  Similar issues have caused security bugs; see e.g. http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html

Instead, rewrite your functions to initialize variables with their eventual correct value at declaration; this may require writing lots of small functions, using ternary expressions etc., which is generally better style anyway.

Comment: why would the compiler eliminate the NULL check if the pointer were not dereferenced before?

Answer (score 1):

> When there is no appropriate initial value for a variable, isn't it much better to leave it without a value.

In my opinion yes.  Modern compilers are pretty good at catching uninitialised variable errors and the clang static analyser almost spookily perfect.  It's much better to have a compiler catch an issue than put in something that will cause a runtime issue down the line.  For instance, initialising a pointer to NULL will suppress the compiler warning but it won't stop the core dump when you try to dereference it.

**However**, if you are using a modern compiler, you are probably using C99 which means you don't need to declare the variable until you know a sensible value for it.  So that's what I would do.

Comment: IMHO this is half of the correct answer to my question. Let the question stand open, for now. BTW on a side note C89's stubborn insisting on introducing new blocks for declarations could be quite useful for forcing scope restrictions on variables i.e. you declare precisely the scope of every variable, every time.

Comment: @Vorac what's the other half?  I'll see if i can address that too.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the variables is always useful and is a good coding practice.
This could be understand with this example:

an uninitialized variable will contain some garbage value in it. And if you didn't initialize it and by mistake you tried to use it. You could get some unpredicted results.
For example:

```
int test(void)
{
    int a; //uninitialized variable

    //You didn't initialize a  
    if(a > 10) 
    {
          //Unpredicted result
    }
    else{}
    return 0;
}
```

The situation becomes severe in case of bigger programs, where these types of miss are common.
So to avoid silly errors which might otherwise could consume lot of time in debugging them, variables should always be initialized

Comment: If you have `-Wall` on as you always should, the warning will tell you about the uninitialised a.  On the other hand, if you guess a value that's wrong, you will get a runtime bug later on.